# Way to know if a user is Logged in ,across a Facebook Application.

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

So I am building an application using Facebook login and authenthication. Everything is fine and dandy using the code below (as per the doc)

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

My Question is how do I tell if the user is logged in without doing all of the above all over again elsewhere. For example in my view how would I be able to quickly test if a user is logged in or not?
Would I simply call `Facebook::getUser()` if so it didn't work in my Codeigniter application. I tried the code below in my view.

```
$user =  Facebook::getUser();
```

and got the error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$user

Filename: src/base_facebook.php

Line Number: 504


Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::getUserFromAvailableData() in /home/syklone911/webapps/meme/application/libraries/facebook/src/base_facebook.php on line 509
```

Can someone shed some light on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file inside **application/config** folder and name it **facebook.php** with contents:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config['appId'] = 'your_app_id';
$config['secret'] = 'your_app_secret';
```

Create a folder inside **application/libraries** and name it **facebook** with contents (facebook php SDK files):

- base_facebook.php
- Facebook.php **note**:(rename facebook.php to Facebook.php and in first line add:

  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
- fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt

When you want to **load the library** in any of your controllers, you simply do:

```
$config = $this->load->config('facebook', TRUE);  
$this->load->library('facebook/facebook', $config);
```

In your view to test if a user is logged in or not:

```
$user = $this->facebook->getUser();  
if($user){
    try{
        $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');
        $access_token = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
    }catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $user = null;
    }
}
if($user){  
    //User is logged in via Facebook  
}else{  
    //User is not logged. Prompt the user to log in via Facebook  
    echo '<a href="'.$this->facebook->getLoginUrl().'">Login Via Facebook</a>';
}
```

That s all.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to store needed facebook data in some sort of session variables so you can use all over the application

and better clean coding practice you may have middle controller MY_Controller with session check and if user is logged in or not and set super object in your middle controller

Answer (score 0):

After `if($user)` place 
`if( session_id() ){}
   else { session_start() ; }`  And at the start of every page you must use this `if( session_id() ){}
   else { session_start() ; }` ,whatever data you want to use in across all your page,you should store that in session variable like this: `$_SESSION['VARIABLE_NAME'] ='DATA TO STORE'` this will keep that data alive on all your pages.
NOTE:You Must initiate facebook class on everypage you want to use GRAPH API on.
i.e 
`require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));`